# Как заполнить все нули в столбце самым первым встретившимся ненулевым значением?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

В столбце фрейма данных есть много нулей прежде, чем пойдут конкретные значения.

Как заполнить все нули в столбце самым первым встретившимся ненулевым значением?

Ссылка на [файл с примером данных](https://dropmefiles.com/YQH60).

```
6/20/2000   0
6/21/2000   0
6/22/2000   0
6/23/2000   400
6/26/2000   200
6/27/2000   2200
6/28/2000   500
6/29/2000   0
6/30/2000   12100
```

Первое число - 400, тогда заполняем все нули до него значением 400:

```
6/20/2000   400
6/21/2000   400
6/22/2000   400
6/23/2000   400
6/26/2000   200
6/27/2000   2200
6/28/2000   500
6/29/2000   0
6/30/2000   12100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наверное, можно как-то и проще, но я не умею:

```
import pandas as pd

# создаём датафрейм с примером данных
df = pd.DataFrame({'data': [0,0,0,2,34,0,3,4,5,0]})
# заполняем NA начало данных, пока идут нули
df.loc[df.data.cumsum() == 0, 'data'] = pd.NA
# заполнение NA проходом "назад"
df['data'] = df['data'].bfill()
df
```

Вывод:

```
    data
0   2
1   2
2   2
3   2
4   34
5   0
6   3
7   4
8   5
9   0
```

Answer (score 2):

Показываю, как это сделать на Series.  Надеюсь, переделать для DataFrame для вас труда не составит.

Итак, если мы хотим все нули, которые идут ДО ПОЯВЛЕНИЯ первого значения заменить на это самое первое значение, то сделать это можно примерно вот так:

```
ser=pd.Series([0,0,0,400,200,220,0,500,0,0,12,0,100])
ser[:ser[ser!=0].index[0]]=ser[ser!=0].iloc[0]
```

Результат:

```
0     400
1     400
2     400
3     400
4     200
5     220
6       0
7     500
8       0
9       0
10     12
11      0
12    100
```

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае можно воспользоваться методом [Series.first_valid_index()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.first_valid_index.html):

```
last_zero_idx = df["C-B"].replace(0, np.nan).first_valid_index() - 1
df.loc[:last_zero_idx, "C-B"] = df.loc[last_zero_idx+1, "C-B"]
```